# find the highest occurrence of a point type

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How to get the highest repetition for a point type data in PgSQL

**Need to calculate the most repeated coordinate** (more precisely within a range of 100 meters)

Sample data column name **coordinates**

```
user_id                                           coordinates
11ce4d96-4f64-421e-a56d-d436a804e522              (22.34,454.455)
11ce4d96-4f64-421e-a56d-d436a804e522              (12.2323,90.23233)
11ce4d96-4f64-421e-a56d-d436a804e522              (28.6986724,77.2972819)
11ce4d96-4f64-421e-a56d-d436a804e522              (28.6986176,77.2972501)
11ce4d96-4f64-421e-a56d-d436a804e522              (28.6987351,77.2973343)
11ce4d96-4f64-421e-a56d-d436a804e522              (28.6986208,77.2972428)
be34f634-4ab3-4407-89ac-8f79e2d62232              (28.6987699,77.2972538)
be34f634-4ab3-4407-89ac-8f79e2d62232              (28.6987699,77.2972538)
be34f634-4ab3-4407-89ac-8f79e2d62232              (28.6987699,77.2972538)
be34f634-4ab3-4407-89ac-8f79e2d62232              (28.6987699,77.2972538)
be34f634-4ab3-4407-89ac-8f79e2d62232              (28.6987259,77.2972478)
be34f634-4ab3-4407-89ac-8f79e2d62232              (28.6986413,77.2972698)
```

Comment: The requirement is not clear: are you looking for repetitions or do you want to find the biggest cluster?

Comment: Please add expected result and a little more explanation.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored function or procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to find the most repeated coordinated assuming this all data belongs to a single user, to get the user's correct location

Comment: @Don . . . If you have a user, why isn't that part of the sample data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have update the sample data thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct on (user) user, point(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]), count(*)
from t
group by user, coordinates[0], coordinates[1]
order by user, count(*) desc;
```

It seems to be what you are describing.

Comment: getting this `ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type point` as coordinates is a point type